# A cyclic inequality of degree 10

Tags: inequality, summation, alternative-proof, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

Suppose that $x,y,z\geq 0$. I would like to prove that
$$(x^5+y^5+z^5)^2\geq (x+y+z)(x^3y^6+y^3z^6+z^3x^6).$$
I can prove this inequality using some standard methods. For example, I can let $x=1, y=1+p$, and $z=1+p+q$. Then Mathematica can simplify the difference of the two sides of the inequality to show that all of the coefficients are positive. I don't like this solution, since it relies heavily on a complicated algebraic simplification. Do you have a better proof?

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

After homogenization we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^{10}+2x^5y^5-x^7z^3-x^6z^4-x^6z^3y)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^7z^3-x^6z^3y)+\sum_{cyc}(x^{10}-2x^7z^3-x^6z^4+2x^5y^5)\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM and SOS:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^7z^3-x^6z^3y)+\sum_{cyc}(x^{10}-2x^7z^3-x^6z^4+2x^5y^5)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{37}\sum_{cyc}(30x^7z^3+4y^7x^3+3z^7y^3-37x^6z^3y)+\sum_{cyc}(x^{10}+2x^5y^5-x^4y^6-2x^3y^7)\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt[37]{\left(x^7z^3\right)^{30}\left(y^7x^3\right)^4\left(z^7y^3\right)^3}-x^6z^3y\right)+$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}x^3(x-y)(x^6+x^5y+x^4y^2+x^3y^3+x^2y^4+3xy^5+2y^6)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\left(x^3(x-y)(x^6+x^5y+x^4y^2+x^3y^3+x^2y^4+3xy^5+2y^6)-(x^{10}-y^{10})\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}y^5(x-y)^2(2x^3+3x^2y+2xy^2+y^3)\geq0.$$
The following inequality is also true.

> Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be non-negative numbers. Prove that:
> $$(x^5+y^5+z^5)^2\geq(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^7y+y^7z+z^7x).$$

Comment: What does SOS refer to?

Comment: @Marco It's Sum Of Squares method. If you want I am ready to explain this proof.

Comment: Please do explain!

Comment: @Marco I added something, See now.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the proof and it is a good proof. In your first draft though it sounded like by referring to SOS one would know how to proceed. Without the algebraic factorizations at the end (which I won't be able to come up with), would the SOS method be so straightforward to apply here?

Comment: @Marco Any polynomial inequality, which we can prove by AM-GM, we can prove also by SOS. But it's very ugly.

Comment: Michael, can you share the source/solution for the inequality you mentioned at the end of your solution?

Comment: @Marco It's mine.

Comment: It looks great! Does it follow from similar techniques?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It is great ... because $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)(x^8 + y^8 + z^8) \geqslant (x^5 + y^5 + z^5)^2$ by simple C-S but replacing $x^8 + y^8 + z^8$ with $x^7y + y^7z + z^7x$ changes the sign of inequality, that is great!

Comment: @Marco  No. It's much more harder. I have no a nice proof of this inequality.

Comment: @Book Of Flames  I like to create inequality which looks nice. Thank you.