# Cyclic Inequality involving four variables

Tags: inequality

Here is an inequality that I think is true for all nonnegative $x,y,z,t$:
$$(x^3+y^3+z^3+t^3)^2 \geq (x+y+z+t)(x^4y+y^4z+z^4t+t^4x).$$
If any two of the variables are equal, I can show the inequality holds (by letting for example $x=y=1$, $z=1+p$, and $t=1+p+q$ for $p,q \geq 0$, and expanding). I also tried using the method of Lagrange multipliers by using the constraint $x+y+z+t=1$, but the algebra gets out of hand. See also a [similar inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3851194/a-cyclic-inequality-of-degree-10/3851245?noredirect=1#comment7957866_3851245) I posted earlier and its solution. I could not replicate the ideas of that solution. So my question is that is this inequality true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequality does not true, please check $x = \frac{7}{10}, \,y = \frac 23, \,z = 1,\,t = \frac{10}{11}.$

Comment: Just because you have a counter example, does that really mean that the conjecture can't be *proven*?  Perhaps what is really being tested here is the OP's creativity.